# GitX - How do you view a single file's commit history?

Tags: git, gitx

Using GitX, how do I view the revision history for a single file? (using the command-line interface preferably)

E.g using GitK this is rather simple;

```
$ gitk app/models/activity.rb
```

Answer (score 12):

try

```
gitx -- app/models/activity.rb
```

make sure you run the command at the repository root otherwise gitx will appear empty

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it always goes to the full history

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [@rgcb said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981986/3357935) but make sure you are at the top level of the repository.

```
gitx -- app/models/activity.rb
```

not

```
gitx -- ./activity.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way, but with `gitx` instead:

```
$ gitx app/models/activity.rb
```

Note that all the commits shown will include the specified file, but the *full* commit will be shown (i.e., it'll show changes for other files modified in that commit).

Comment: No dice (I'm running Version 0.7.1).

Comment: I tried it before posting the answer, and it worked. What happens when you do it?

Comment: GitX shows me nada: See screenshot here: https://skitch.com/glennr/r4r59/health-resource-tracker1-branch-improve-submit-page